# FOSS way of creating space time cube?

Tags: open-source-gis, software-recommendations, visualisation, netcdf, space-time-cube

I've been experimenting with ArcGIS Pro's "Visualizing Space Time Cube" tool but found that there is a feature limitation when I try to publish it via ArcGIS Online. My goal is to publish it on the web so end-users can interact with the cube for the whole study area. However, using ArcGIS Pro limits the study area which leads me to exploring the open source way.

I did some searching but my initial findings came up short. Has there been a FOSS solution in creating a space time cube? The subject matter is mapping fire occurrences of a national park over 15 years using a bin size of 3 months/1 mile.

Comment: THREDDS and NetCDF are usual on the publishing side for multidimensional data, but its hard to say what will be useful for publishing without knowing what the source data format is.

Comment: The raw shapefile is: [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0X0uxRRD8_TUUtMR2lEbC1OT0U). One of the processed netCDF files is: [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_zBNzuYZ6W0R0VZOFVwTFhzZVE) Hopefully that works.

Comment: R's raster package, and mapview for vis.

Comment: thank you both for the help! I'll check it out and come back with results.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to stay in the GIS context, there is feature rich temporal data processing included in GRASS GIS 7. It is free and open source software, available from https://grass.osgeo.org . The temporal backend handles raster, vector and raster3D times series considering also the temporal topology. The tools include space-time map algebra, gap-filling, aggregation etc. as well as time series visualization. See details at

- Overview: https://grass.osgeo.org/grass72/manuals/temporalintro.html
- Wiki: https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Temporal_data_processing
- Tutorial: http://ncsu-geoforall-lab.github.io/grass-temporal-workshop/

Since export was asked here, there is for example VTK export supported:

- https://grass.osgeo.org/grass72/manuals/t.rast.out.vtk.html

which is e.g. read by ParaView: http://www.paraview.org/

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps [Nanocubes](https://github.com/laurolins/nanocube) would be worth a look.

Developed out of AT&T Labs, presented at the 2013 VIS Conference I think.